# Inner element does not extends parent height element

Tags: html, css, react-masonry

Why green element does not extends blue elements heights?

I cant set this to work properly,is there any solution to make deeper element to extend container?Yellow must have fixed height its is a masonry grid in real life example and i dont know why it doesnt stretch to inner elements properly.

```css
.blue {

  width:100vw;
  min-height:100vh;
  background-color:blue;
  padding:5px;
}

.yellow {

  background-color:yellow;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  padding:5px;

}

.green {

  background-color:green;
  height:1500px;
  width:50px;

}
```

```html
<div class="blue">

  <div class="yellow">
  
    <div class="green">
    
    
    </div>
  
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want. Is this?

```css
.blue {
  float:left;
  width:100vw;
  min-height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
  padding:5px;
}

.yellow {

  background-color:yellow;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  padding:5px;

}

.green {
  float:left;
  background-color:green;
  height:1500px;
  width:50px;

}
```

```html
<div class="blue">

  <div class="yellow">
  
    <div class="green">
    
    
    </div>
  
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yeah thats seems to work in this example but `float:left` property spoils my layout